# managedbean live cycle listener

Tags: jsf-2.2, managed-bean

I use a managed bean with a view scoped because I need it ( for a p:datatable with lazy and selection modes ), but i'd like to do some things into this managed bean at the render response phase, is there a convenient way to do that ?

I need a view scoped to save a lazyDataModel, but I noticed that the rowCount method is called several times, each time a request ( Select count ) is executed.

So I deciced to save the result of the request. But if I add a data and refresh the datatable with ajax, the row count still contain the same result because of the scope. I use a boolean to know if the rowcount method has been already executed and I can set this boolean to false each time I add or remove a data but if I could do that a the render response phase it would be more convenient for me.

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public  class ListBean {

    protected MyLazyDataModel myLazyDataModel = new MyLazyDataModel();

    public MyLazyDataModel getMyLazyDataModel() {
        return myLazyDataModel;
    }

    public void reloadList() {
        this.reloadList = true;
    }

    protected class MyLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel{

        private int rowCount ;

        @Override
        public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, 

        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public Object getRowKey(Type object) {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRowData(String rowKey) {
          ...
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {

            if( reloadList ) {
                this.rowCount = getDao().getRowCount().intValue();
                reloadList = false;
            }
            return rowCount;
        }


    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there are a few ways to do that : `viewAction`, Phase Listeners, event listeners. Without some code however, this question's no good.

Comment: thanks you, I don't know if some code would be necessary but I can explain the context.